# Show all the upload fields

Tags: media, files

Is there any way to show all the upload fields on a node?
Right now a user has to upload a single file and then get another field and so forth. Instead I would like to show the max number of permitted upload fields.

Answer (score 1):

The add another option only appear if you choose unlimited in field settings. 
If you choose an exact number say 5, it will display 5 image upload fields always.
Its the default property.